# Error: "project "path/to/file.rda" has no activated script and so cannot be activated" with renv

Tags: r, renv

I am trying to use `renv` with my project pipeline in R.

My folder structure is

```
.
|-- data
|   |-- file1.rda
|   |-- file2.rda
|   |-- folder1
|   |-- folder2
`-- repository
    |-- rep1
    |   |-- script1.R
    |   |-- script2.R
    |   |-- config.json
    `-- rep2
```

`/rep1` is the folder of my analysis pipeline and the folder I am running my scripts from. I am keeping track of the packages I am using with `renv`, which I initialised in `/rep1`, but I have not created a snapshot yet.

`/data` contains `file*.rda`, which are produced by `script1.R` and have a considerable size. I cannot move any of them in my `/rep1` folder. In order to use them with `script2.R`, I am calling them with

```
library(renv)
library(jsonlite)
config <- read_json("config.json")

load(file.path(config$data_folder, "file1.rda"))
```

and they should load the object stored in them.

Whenever I run that, though, I get the following error:

```
Error: project "~/data/file1.rda" has no activate script and so cannot be activated
Traceback (most recent calls last):
4: load(file.path(config$data_folder, "file1.rda"))                                 
3: renv_load_switch(project)
2: stopf(fmt, renv_path_pretty(project))                                       
1: stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
```

Am I missing something? I have the impression something is going wrong when I switch the folder, but I am not really sure how to fix this.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `renv::load()` is masking `base::load()`. In general, you should not call `library(renv)` in your scripts -- instead, you should prefix any `renv` APIs you want to use with `renv::`.

Alternatively, explicitly call `base::load()` to ensure the right version of `load()` is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it, I am editing my question so that it includes the library call